# Android: Activity, содержащее список и вкладки.

Tags: android, java

Балуюсь около часа с Android и понимаю что что-то делаю не так, но не понимаю что именно.

Вижу кучу разных производных от `Activity` — `ListActivity`, `TabActivity` и иже с ними. Множественного наследования в Java, насколько я слышал, нет — так что такое разделение намекает мне, что не может быть такого activity, чтобы было, скажем, и списком, и вкладками. Создал layout с `ListView` и `TabWidget` — возникли проблемы как управлять всем этим хозяйством — если со списком нашел как работать их просто `Activity`, то со вкладками уже не нахожу.

Подозреваю, что раз дизайн сопротивляется, то мой подход неверен. Но в чем?

И как все это правильно структурировать и использовать? Если можно, для простого (надеюсь) примера — «формы», в которой есть список и есть вкладки, в которых сгруппированы несколько чекбоксов. Т.е., условно, псевдографикой:

```
LinearLayout на три ряда с содержимым:
+------------------------------------------+
| Фильмы                                   |  <-- ListView (множ. выбор)
| Музыка                                   |
+------------------------------------------+
| [  Владелец  ] [ Группа ] [ Остальные  ] |  <-- TabWidget (tabs)
|/              \__________________________|
| [x] Чтение                               |  <-- FrameLayout (tabcontent)
| [x] Запись                               |
+------------------------------------------+
|                            [ Сохранить ] |  <-- Button
+------------------------------------------+
```

Пример упрощенный, теоретический. Понятно, что в этом случае лучше бы чекбоксы и в GridLayout затолкать.

Спасибо, но это только список (причем мне, в моем случае, простого `ArrayAdapter<String>` хватило). А у мне непонятно стало, когда появился *и* список *и* вкладки. Причем вкладки не являются какой-то особенностью activity, так что делать его `TabActivity` вроде как нелогично.

При всем этом, меня больше интересует не как сделать чтобы оно просто работало, а как сделать, чтобы оно не только работало, но и было архитектурно правильно.

Comment: методом тыка решил разобраться?

Comment: Типа того. Почитал вводную и решил, что надо попробовать что-то сделать на практике. Напихал виджетов, начал их инициализировать и споткнулся о `ListActivity`/`TabActivity` (в примерах везде они) и сам себя запутал. Сейчас, вроде бы, картина проясняется.

Comment: кстати, если надо взять какой-то другой layout (например custom_layout.xml)
и есть например LinearLayout в main.xml  с id=llMain
можно сделать так

LinearLayout llContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMain);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, llMain, false);
llContent.addView(view);

Это если вам что-то динамически надо добавить в контейнер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляете список в layout (допустим android:id="@+id/lvItems")

Затем в активити

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoyt);
ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(...);
lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);

// чтобы обрабатывать нажатия на элемент (если нужно)
// при этом ваш Activity должен еще реализовывать интерфейс AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
lvNotes.setOnItemClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     //обработка нажатия
}
```

Также можете добавлять другие виджеты и обрабатывать их
Развернуто совсем тут писать не буду (не знаю тут личка есть или нет, напишите если помощь нужна будет)

пример простенький, времени к сожалению особо нет

в общем тут вроде набор как нарисован

в первом табе текствью, в него записываются все действия

Manifest: http://pastebin.com/kWvmrvgP

ListTabActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/LsBqpe4C

main.xml (layout): http://pastebin.com/ndPkUwed

Comment: Спасибо, но это только список (причем мне, в моем случае, простого `ArrayAdapter<String>` хватило). А у мне непонятно стало, когда появился *и* список *и* вкладки. Причем вкладки не являются какой-то особенностью activity, так что делать его `TabActivity` вроде как нелогично.

И, при всем этом, меня больше интересует не как сделать чтобы просто работало, а как сделать, чтобы было архитектурно правильно.

Comment: Дак вкладки и списки на самом деле это не Activity, это View
Это просто виджеты, такие же как кнопка например
Просто ищите их в коде и обрабатываете как вам надо. Постараюсь накидать Вам пример сегодня.

Comment: архитектурно. берем активити, которая содержит вкладки - другие активити

Comment: Activity не может содержать другие activity. View может содержать другие View.

Comment: Понял, пойду почитаю про view. За пример — заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Добавил небольшой пример в ответ

Comment: О, вижу пример, вроде бы осознал. Большое спасибо!